# Did the user use the URL bar?

Tags: url, block, referrer

I need to know if someone navigated to a specific page of my app using the URL bar or if they clicked a link to get there.

I want to prevent users from being able to use the URL bar to navigate to some pages.

The issue is **I cannot use HTTP referrer** because my app doesn't load a new page when the URL changes.  It just loads new data on the page so my referrer is always the login screen.  Also there are various triggers that change the URL to load this data automatically so I would need to know for sure the user specifically typed in the the url bar and hit enter.

**Is there any other way of knowing the user entered something from the URL bar so I can block the request?**

Comment: Why do you want to block users from visiting a page directly if they have a valid URL for that page? That would break useful features that users expect support for, like bookmarks and copying and pasting URLs. Is it for security – checking that the user is logged in? If so, I can explain a better way to restrict pages to logged-in users.

Comment: It is an app that the user shouldn't need to use the URL bar to navigate.  It has a very specific purpose and using the URL bar bypasses the security checks we have to see if that user has access to view certain pages.  The app is all in one page and never reloads or changes pages but the URL bar changes when certain JS files and HTML files are loaded on the screen.  hitting the back button will always take you to the login screen because it never actually loads a new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you’re saying your page loads HTML files dynamically from the server using a JavaScript API such as [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), then uses the JavaScript [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to update the URL with the name of the HTML file that was loaded? So the first URL is `/page?name=logincheck.html`, and then it changes the URL to `/page?name=thetool.html` after performing the login check, without the page reloading?

If that’s how your app works, theoretically you could disable the URL rewriting – the app can still know what page it is on because the JavaScript can save the current page to a variable. Then users would never see the URL with `thetool.html` that bypasses the login check. But this setup will not protect you from a malicious hacker who is able to guess that `thetool.html` is a page that exists.

If you want to prevent people from loading a specific page, the correct place to check for this is **on the server-side**. If you did the security checks in JavaScript, a malicious user could tell their browser to ignore that JavaScript, and run their own JavaScript instead that doesn’t do the check.

How to check on the server side whether someone has logged in depends on what server software you are using (Apache Server, a Java Spring MVC app, a Ruby on Rails app) and how your current login page currently tells the rest of your software that the user has logged in (a cookie, a row in a `sessions` table in a database, a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/) saved to local storage). I can’t give instructions without knowing the software and authentication method you’re using, but I can tell you it’s possible.

In general, logging in should both tell the server to create a new user session, and save a cookie in the browser referencing that session. Whenever a browser requests a protected page, the server software should first check if a session cookie was sent, and if the session cookie corresponds to a currently-valid session. If it does not, the server software should send an empty page with the [403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) status code instead of the actual page.

Comment: There is a login page then it loads the app after you log in. Once on the app it behaves as you stated above.  JS and HTML is loaded dynamically without loading entire new pages even though the URL changes.  Hitting reload logs you out and hitting back also logs you out and takes you to the last page you were on, AKA the login screen

Disabling URL rewriting may work but it might break all the JS and PHP code that is using parts of the path or setting the path/URL to be something

I'm trying to work around the way this was designed so i was hoping for a quick fix.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion though.  It's probably how this app should have been built in the first place. unfortunately it was built such that the URL bar controls everything so I was hoping to just find a way of disabling it for the user so they have to use the app to access certain things.

Comment: I actually applied the user security checks in javascript for when the state changes to load that specific data but i was told that our admins set those up for their users and the admins are unreliable so if i add this security check, many users will be locked down when they shouldnt be.  For this reason, i cannot include the security check on the server side when the page loads either.  My alternative solution was to prevent them from using the URL bar but it doesnt seem viable now :(

Comment: and by security i mean,  once a user is logged in their security profile allows them to access certain pages.  i dont really mean app access in general.  we have that covered through the login screen